# Ejabberd performance issues

Tags: performance, networking, ejabberd

I try to stress test ejabberd with bots. Bots are sending messages to each other. When load reaches 30 MB/s it seems that something is limiting the traffic.

I disables all shapers and most of the ejabberd plugins, but it doesn't help. The server that runs the test has a lot of resources available (CPU, RAM, Bandwidth etc).

Does anybody know how to properly tune ejabberd that it runs without such a limitation?

p.s. Maybe somebody can suggest similar to XMPP transport that can handle high load (up to 1 Gbit) and many connection (up to 250 000 per powerful server)?

Comment: Which OS(s) are you experiencing the problem on?

Comment: Are you logging something? Have you checked disk throughput utilization?